# No provider for ControlContainer when a child component has a ngModelGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I can't seem to figure this out, it's simply not working.

This is the original [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/LLf7Il/) which is written by Pascal Prekht , which is an explanation on template driven forms:

And [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/Q8pjSIVJHhfubILtvqWw/) is my fork which is exactly the same thing , except I'm trying to load one of the fieldsets as a separate child component.

Here is the code :

```
@Component({
  selector:'form-group-component',
  template:`
    <fieldset ngModelGroup="anotherAddress">
      <div>
        <label>Street2:</label>
        <input type="text" name="street2" ngModel>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

  `
})
export class FormGroupComponent{

}

@Component({
  selector: 'form-component',
  directives:[FormGroupComponent],
  template: `
    <form #form="ngForm">

      <form-group-component></form-group-component>  

      <fieldset ngModelGroup="address">
        <div>
          <label>Street:</label>
          <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Zip:</label>
          <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>City:</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

    </form>
  `
})
export class FormComponent {


}
```

So after cutting one of the feildsets and loading it inside a seperate directive , it won't work anymore!,

There are couple of closed issues , but non of them is working.

[This](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/399)  
and [This](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6374)

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old question. But somebody in future may find it useful. I had same issue and looks like the error appears  when a component has a `<form>` tag without a `formGroup` directive and the module is importing 
`ReactiveFormModule`. So to fix the issue make sure that all the `<form>` tags have `formGroup` directive, if their module is importing `ReactiveFormModule`.

Comment: I had the same error with reactive forms in different "feature modules". I had to import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in my feature module too (instead of only importing these in the app.module.ts).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **template driven forms**, and have a *sub-component* for part of the form, and (finally) want to use **ngModelGroup** in that *sub-component*, you need to provide **ControlContainer** to the view.

Quick solution:

- import `ControlContainer, NgForm` in the sub-component:

  `import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';`
- add those as `viewProviders` in the sub-component `@Component` decorator:

```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-question',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

- details in an awesome article from Alexey Zuev: https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

Answer (score -1):

Quick import on app.modules.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
ReactiveFormsModule],})
```